# How to save image uploaded from firebase storage to currentUser in firestore database

Tags: reactjs, firebase-realtime-database, react-hooks, firebase-authentication, firebase-storage

I'm unsure of how to get the image url that was uploaded to firebase storage and save it to the firestore database. Currently i have a Profile component that stores the logic for a user to upload a photo to firebase storage. I have a UserContext file which listens for user changes. As-well as a Firebase.utils which creates the user.

Firebase.utils file:

```
import firebase from 'firebase/compat/app';
import 'firebase/compat/firestore';
import 'firebase/compat/auth';
import "firebase/compat/storage";

const config = {
    apiKey: "",
    authDomain: "",
    projectId: "",
    storageBucket: "",
    messagingSenderId: "",
    appId: "",
    measurementId: ""
};

firebase.initializeApp(config);

export const createUserProfileDocument = async (userAuth, additionalData) => {
    // If user is not signed in do nothing
    if (!userAuth) return;

    const userRef = firestore.doc(`users/${userAuth.uid}`)

    const snapShot = await userRef.get()

    if (!snapShot.exists) {
        // Added photoURL @@@
        const { displayName, email, photoURL } = userAuth;
        const createdAt = new Date();

        try {
            await userRef.set({
                displayName,
                email,
                createdAt,
                photoURL,
                ...additionalData
            })
        } catch (error) {
            console.log('error creating user', error.message)
        }
    }

    return userRef;
}

export const auth = firebase.auth();
export const firestore = firebase.firestore();
const storage = firebase.storage();; 

export { storage, firebase as default };
```

The UserContext file:

```
import React, { useContext, useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { auth, createUserProfileDocument } from "../Firebase/Firebase.utils";

const UserContext = React.createContext(null);
const UserUpdateContext = React.createContext();
const UserUpdateNameContext = React.createContext();
const UserUpdateEmailContext = React.createContext();

export const useUserContext = () => {
    // useContext hook 
    return useContext(UserContext);
}

export const useUserContextUpdate = () => {
    // useContext hook - toggleUser signout function
    return useContext(UserUpdateContext)
}

export const useUserNameUpdate = () => {
    // useContext hook - update user displayName
    return useContext(UserUpdateNameContext)
}

export const useUserEmailUpdate = () => {
    // useContext hook - update user email
    return useContext(UserUpdateEmailContext)
}

export const UserContextProvider = ({ children }) => {
    const [currentUser, setUser] = useState(null);
    let unsubscribeFromAuth = null;
    console.log(currentUser)

    useEffect(() => {
        unsubscribeFromAuth = auth.onAuthStateChanged(async userAuth => {
            if (userAuth) {
                const userRef = await createUserProfileDocument(userAuth);

                userRef.onSnapshot(snapShot => {
                    setUser({
                        id: snapShot.id,
                        ...snapShot.data()
                    });
                });
            } else {
                setUser(null)
                // setUser({ currentUser: userAuth }) OBJECTS ARE TRUTHY 
            }
        });

        return () => {
            unsubscribeFromAuth();
        };
    }, [])
    console.log(unsubscribeFromAuth)

    const toggleUser = () => {
        auth.signOut()
            .then(() => {
                setUser(null)
            })
            .catch(e => console.log('There was a error:'(e)))
    }
    // console.log(currentUser)

    // Get current window width
    const useWindowWidth = () => {
        const [width, setWidth] = useState(window.innerWidth)
        useEffect(() => {
            const handleResize = () => setWidth(window.innerWidth)
            window.addEventListener('resize', handleResize)
            return () => {
                window.removeEventListener('resize', handleResize)
            }
        })
        return width
    }
    const width = useWindowWidth();

    // Slice off end of displayName if reaches a certain length
    const sliceDisplayName = (currentUser) => {
        if (currentUser) {
            const displayName = currentUser.displayName;
            return (
                width >= 1441 ? displayName.substring(0, 16) + '...'
                    : width <= 1440 && width >= 769 ? displayName.substring(0, 14) + '...'
                        : width <= 768 ? displayName.substring(0, 7) + '...'
                            : displayName
            )
        } else (console.log("No user found :("))
    }
    // console.log(sliceDisplayName(currentUser))

    // Slice off end of email if reaches a certain length
    const sliceEmail = (currentUser) => {
        if (currentUser) {
            const email = currentUser.email;
            return (
                width >= 1441 ? email.substring(0, 16) + '...'
                    : width <= 1440 && width >= 769 ? email.substring(0, 14) + '...'
                        : width <= 768 ? email.substring(0, 7) + '...'
                            : email
            )
        } else (console.log("No user found :("))
    }
    // console.log(sliceEmail(currentUser))

    return (
        <UserContext.Provider value={currentUser} >
            <UserUpdateContext.Provider value={toggleUser} >
                <UserUpdateNameContext.Provider value={sliceDisplayName} >
                    <UserUpdateEmailContext.Provider value={sliceEmail} >
                        {children}
                    </UserUpdateEmailContext.Provider >
                </UserUpdateNameContext.Provider >
            </UserUpdateContext.Provider >
        </UserContext.Provider >
    )
};
```

The Profile Component:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import ReactTooltip from 'react-tooltip';
import { useUserContext, useUserContextUpdate, useUserNameUpdate } from '../../Utilities/Context/UserContext';
import { storage } from "../../Utilities/Firebase/Firebase.utils";
import { ref, uploadBytesResumable, getDownloadURL } from "firebase/storage"; 
import ActivityFeed from '../../../src/components/ActivityFeed/ActivityFeed';
import Post from '../../../src/components/Post/Post';

import './Profile.css';

const Profile = ({ imageDate }) => {
    const currentUser = useUserContext(); // Current user
    const sliceDisplayName = useUserNameUpdate(); // Window width < (width) ? update displayName length
    const [image, setImage] = useState("");
    const [url, setUrl] = useState("");

    // Listen for state changes, errors, and completion of the upload.
    const handleUpload = () => {
        const uploadTask = storage.ref(`images/${image.name}`).put(image);
        uploadTask.on('state_changed',
            (snapshot) => { console.log(snapshot) },
            (error) => {
                switch (error.code) {
                    case 'storage/unauthorized':
                        break;
                    case 'storage/canceled':
                        break;
                    case 'storage/unknown':
                        break;
                }
            },
            (e) => {
                storage
                    .ref("images")
                    .child(image.name)
                    .getDownloadURL(uploadTask.snapshot.ref)
                    .then(url => {
                        setUrl(url);
                        console.log('File available at', url);
                    })
            }
        );
    }
    console.log("image: ", image);
    console.log(image.lastModifiedDate) // Image date uploaded. image.lastmodifiedDate === undefined ? 
    console.log(url)

    const handleUploadChange = e => { // Maybe inside this function i can do the logic for recent activity and 0 photos +1
        if (e.target.files[0]) {
            setImage(e.target.files[0]);
        }
    };

    return (
        <div className="container-flex">
            <div className="top-content-container w-100">
                <div className="bot-content-wrapper px-1 py-2 mx-lg-auto d-flex flex-column flex-lg-row">
                    <div className="w-spacer profile-image-wrapper position-relative">
                        {
                            currentUser ?
                                <input
                                    type="file"
                                    for="Upload Image"
                                    accept="image/*"
                                    name="image"
                                    id="file"
                                    onChange={handleUploadChange}
                                    onClick={handleUploadChange}
                                    style={{ display: "none" }}
                                />
                                : ''
                        
                        }
                        <label for="file">  
                            {
                                url.length <= 0 ?
                                    <img
                                        id='myimg'
                                        className="profile-image-default profile-image d-block"
                                        alt=""
                                    />
                                : currentUser ?
                                    <>
                                        <img
                                            id='myimg'
                                            className="profile-image d-block"
                                            src={url}
                                            alt=""
                                            data-tip="Click me to update profile picture!" />                                    
                                        <ReactTooltip place="top" type="dark" effect="float" />
                                    </>
                                :
                                    <img
                                        id='myimg'
                                        className="profile-image-default profile-image d-block"
                                        alt=""
                                    />
                            }
                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <div className="d-flex flex-column flex-lg-row align-items-lg-center w-lg-75 m-l-4">
                        <div className="d-flex flex-column flex-lg-row ml-auto pr-1 m-r-md-vw">
                            <div className="m-r-md">
                                <div className="d-flex flex-column w-100 m-r-6">
                                    <div>
                                        {
                                            currentUser ?
                                                <h2
                                                    data-tip={currentUser.displayName}>
                                                    {sliceDisplayName(currentUser)}
                                                    <span><ReactTooltip place="top" type="dark" effect="float" /></span>
                                                </h2>
                                                :
                                                <h2>No User</h2>
                                        }
                                    </div>
                                    <div className="d-flex flex-column flex-lg-row">
                                        <div className="">
                                            <i className="bi bi-people"></i>
                                            <span className="banner-list-font mx-1">0 friends</span>
                                        </div>
                                        <div className="mx-lg-2">
                                            <i className="bi bi-star"></i>
                                            <span className="banner-list-font mx-1">0 reviews</span>
                                        </div>
                                        <div className="">
                                            <i className="bi bi-camera"></i>
                                            <span className="banner-list-font mx-1">0 photos</span>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <hr className=" d-lg-none" style={{ color: '#0a0a0a' }}></hr>
                            <div className="ml-3">
                                <div className="update-profile-wrapper grey-line-break d-flex flex-column m-l">
                                    <div className="">
                                        {
                                            image.name !== undefined ?
                                                <button
                                                    className="banner-list-font"
                                                    onClick={handleUpload}
                                                    //  onClick={() => {
                                                    //      handleUpload();
                                                    //      forceUpdate();
                                                    //  }}
                                                >Add Profile Photo
                                                </button>
                                                : ''
                                        }
                                    </div>
                                    <div className="">
                                        <a className="banner-list-font" href='#'>Update Your Profile</a>
                                    </div>
                                    <div className="">
                                        <a className="banner-list-font" href='#'>Find Friends</a>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div className="bot-content-container px-1 py-4 custom-padding">
                <div className="bot-content-wrapper mx-lg-auto d-flex flex-column flex-lg-row">
                    <div className="sidebar d-flex flex-column mx-auto mx-lg-0 mt-lg-5 py-lg-2 px-2">
                        {
                            currentUser ?
                                <h4 className="mb-3">{currentUser.displayName}</h4>
                                :
                                <h4 className="mb-3">No User</h4>
                        }
                        <ul className="p-0">
                            <a className="cursor-pointer text-decoration-none">
                                <li className="d-flex flex-row sidebar-item sidebar-list-font">
                                    <i className="mx-2 bi bi-person-badge"></i>
                                    <h5 className="sidebar-list-font">Overview</h5>
                                </li>
                                <hr style={{ color: '#0a0a0a' }}></hr>
                            </a>
                            <a className="cursor-pointer text-decoration-none">
                                <li className="d-flex flex-row sidebar-item sidebar-list-font">
                                    <i className="mx-2 bi bi-person-plus"></i>
                                    <h5 className="sidebar-list-font">Friends</h5>
                                </li>
                                <hr style={{ color: '#0a0a0a' }}></hr>
                            </a>
                            <a className="cursor-pointer text-decoration-none">
                                <li className="d-flex flex-row sidebar-item sidebar-list-font">
                                    <i className="mx-2 bi bi-award mx-1"></i>
                                    <h5 className="sidebar-list-font">Reviews</h5>
                                </li>
                                <hr style={{ color: '#0a0a0a' }}></hr>
                            </a>
                            <a className="cursor-pointer text-decoration-none">
                                <li className="d-flex flex-row sidebar-item sidebar-list-font">
                                    <i className="mx-2 bi bi-lightbulb"></i>
                                    <h5 className="sidebar-list-font">Tips</h5>
                                </li>
                                <hr style={{ color: '#0a0a0a' }}></hr>
                            </a>
                            <a className="cursor-pointer text-decoration-none">
                                <li className="d-flex flex-row sidebar-item sidebar-list-font">
                                    <i className="mx-2 bi bi-bookmark-star"></i>
                                    <h5 className="sidebar-list-font">Bookmarks</h5>
                                </li>
                                <hr style={{ color: '#0a0a0a' }}></hr>
                            </a>
                            <a className="cursor-pointer text-decoration-none">
                                <li className="d-flex flex-row sidebar-item sidebar-list-font">
                                    <i className="mx-2 bi bi-bookmarks"></i>
                                    <h5 className="sidebar-list-font">Collections</h5>
                                </li>
                                <hr style={{ color: '#0a0a0a' }}></hr>
                            </a>
                            <a className="cursor-pointer text-decoration-none">
                                <li className="d-flex flex-row sidebar-item sidebar-list-font">
                                    <i className="mx-2 bi bi-calendar-check"></i>
                                    <h5 className="sidebar-list-font">Events</h5>
                                </li>
                                <hr style={{ color: '#0a0a0a' }}></hr>
                            </a>
                            <a className="cursor-pointer text-decoration-none">
                                <li className="d-flex flex-row sidebar-item sidebar-list-font">
                                    <i className="mx-2 bi bi-clock-history"></i>
                                    <h5 className="sidebar-list-font">Order History</h5>
                                </li>
                                <hr style={{ color: '#0a0a0a' }}></hr>
                            </a>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <div className="d-flex flex-column flex-lg-row w-100-md w-75-lg p-3 p-lg-0 m-l-4 pt-lg-3 pt-xl-4">
                        <div className="activity m-l-3">
                            <h3 className="heading-red">Notifications</h3>
                            <p className="font-14">No new friend requests or compliments at this time.</p>
                            <hr className="d-none d-lg-block" style={{ color: '#0a0a0a' }}></hr>
                            <h3 className="heading-red">Recent Activity</h3>
                            {<ActivityFeed />}
                            {<Post />}
                        </div>
                        <hr className="d-lg-none" style={{ color: '#0a0a0a' }}></hr>
                        <div className="grey-line-break ml-3">
                            <h3 className="heading-red mb-1 break-word">About
                                {
                                    currentUser ?
                                        <h3
                                            data-tip={currentUser.displayName}
                                            className="heading-red mb-1">
                                            {sliceDisplayName(currentUser)}
                                            <span><ReactTooltip place="top" type="dark" effect="float" /></span>
                                        </h3>
                                        :
                                        <h3 className="heading-red mb-1">No User</h3>
                                }
                            </h3>
                            <h5 className="about-subHeading mt-2">Yelping Since</h5>
                            <p className="font-14">Some month</p>
                            <h5 className="about-subHeading mt-2">Things I Love</h5>
                            <p className="font-14">You haven't said yet...</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};

export default Profile;
```

**EDIT** 
Updated uploadTask

```
import { createUserProfileDocument } from "../../Utilities/Firebase/Firebase.utils";

    () => {
        storage
            .ref('images/')
            .child(image.name)
            .getDownloadURL(uploadTask.snapshot.ref)
            .then(async (url, firestore, userAuth) => {
                setUrl(url);
                const userRef = firestore.doc(`users/${userAuth.uid}`)
                await userRef.update({
                    photoURL: url
                });
                console.log('File available at', url);
            })
    }
```

Error after update: 
Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'doc')

**EDIT UPDATE #2** 
 
It seems that ive managed to get the uploaded photo from storage to go into the firestore database thanks to the help of Frank van Puffelen. I can see it in console.log of current user in the photoURL and its showing in the firebase db user collection as-well. But if i refresh or go to another page the image goes away, even though its still showing the url in the currentUser console.log even after the refresh. Why would that be happening? It must be because the setUrl(url) reinitializes state of the url image back to nothing on every render. I should be good to ditch this all together and call the image url directly from the currentUser like: currentUser.photoURL

 
Updated code:

```
import { storage, firestore } from "../../Utilities/Firebase/Firebase.utils";

    () => {
        storage
            .ref('images/')
            .child(image.name)
            .getDownloadURL(uploadTask.snapshot.ref)
            .then(async (url) => {
                setUrl(url);
                const userRef = firestore.doc(`users/${currentUser.id}`)
                await userRef.update({
                    photoURL: url
                });
                console.log('File available at', url);
            })
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can see, you upload the image and get its download URL in this snippet:

```
storage
    .ref("images")
    .child(image.name)
    .getDownloadURL(uploadTask.snapshot.ref)
    .then(url => {
        setUrl(url);
        console.log('File available at', url);
    })
```

To also write the new URL to the user's profile document in Firestore, add this to the `then()` callback:

```
const userRef = firestore.doc(`users/${userAuth.uid}`)
await userRef.update({
    photoURL: url
});
```

Comment: Thanks for answering Frank, i updated the question to reflect this... i'm getting an error back (see updated question).

Comment: This can't work: `.then(async (url, firestore, userAuth) => {`. You can't just type variables here, as `getDownloadURL` is not passing those values in. You'll need to find another way to access `firestore` and the UID in there: `const firestore = firebase.firestore();` and `const uid = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;`.

Comment: So just to be clear i can now ditch [url, setUrl] = useState("") and now call the user image with currentUser.photoURL. The url, setUrl is causing the image to disappear on every re-render because state is initializing back to nothing, correct ?

Comment: You need `useState` if you want to update the local React state. If you have a realtime listener to the user's Firestore document, you could also update the UI from that listener, but I don't immediately see that in your code. --- Note that your original problem ("How to save image uploaded from firebase storage to currentUser in firestore database") seems fixed, so I'd recommend moving onto a new question and setting up a new, separate [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)  for that.

Comment: I believe thats covered with the useEffect hook listening auth.onAuthStateChanged(async userAuth => { in UserContext file ?

Comment: That seems to only run when you first create the user. Note: you are really sharing a lot more code than we can reasonably read here, so I recommend another read of [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).